# How to unseal vault after a fresh initialization?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am setting up a Vault test-server on a Windows 10 machine and first time it went well.

But after a reboot I could no longer unseal my vault with my keys. Ok, so I delete the data folder and start vault again.

I Create a new Raft cluster and then enter one key share and threshold. I then get one key and one root key. Great. (Also downloaded the keys)

[image]

So, next I get to the unseal prompt and enter my key, but it won't accept my newly created key!

I have tried several times to delete the data-folder and recreate the keys in the UI, but I can't still get past the unseal window anymore.

[image]

Any hints on what is causing this?

Is key data stored somewhere else besides the \vault\data folder?

My config is:

```
storage "raft" {
  path    = "./vault/data"
  node_id = "node1"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

api_addr = "http://0.0.0.0:8200"
cluster_addr = "https://0.0.0.0:8201"
ui = true
```

I am running version  Vault 1.5.0.

Comment: can you get some logs from Vault and add them ?

Comment: Data is not stored anywhere else, deleting that directory should give you a completely fresh Vault. You will need to restart the server too, of course, which you say you've done. Are you sure you're pasting the correct key into the unseal field?

Answer (score 2):

Found my problem after a lot of troubleshooting.

The problem in my config was that I had set all the IP's to 0.0.0.0 to bind Vault to all IP-addresses, but that did not go so well as planned.

The config that worked for me looked like this

```
storage "raft" {
  path    = "./vault/data"
  node_id = "node1"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  tls_disable = 1
}

api_addr = "http://localhost:8200"
cluster_addr = "https://localhost:8201"
ui = true
```